# How to save an instance of a custom class in onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android

I created an instance of a custom class RestaurantList to hold my data (a list of restaurant data received from a web service as json data).

How can I save it in `onSaveInstanceState`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Custom objects can be saved inside a Bundle when they implement the interface `Parcelable`.
Then they can be saved via:

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("key", myObject);
    }
```

Basically the following methods must be implemented in the class file:

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     /** save object in parcel */
     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     /** recreate object from parcel */
     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I find it to be less work to translate into and back from JSON, compared to parcelable

Comment: onSaveInstanceState should be at the end of the function! https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: While this is the right way to save the custom object in onSaveInstanceState() you should ensure that you do not save big objects using this method. This is just to save the state of the screen. If objects becomes large, there is a chance that you get `TransactionTooLargeException` exception

Comment: @abat can you define "large"?

Comment: onSaveInstanceState is documented in examples at the end of the function. It appears it works either way.

Comment: @Mitch 1MB is the limit. Now with ViewModel and liveData, most of the things can be saved using that pattern

Answer (score 4):

**Kotlin Solution:**
For custom class save in `onSaveInstanceState` you can be converted your class to `JSON` string and restore it with `Gson` convertion. The following example is for `Fragment` and `Activity`:

**For Activity:**

For put class in `saveInstanceState`:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = gson.toJson(your_custom_class)
        outState.putString("CUSTOM_CLASS", json)
    }
```

Restore class:

```
 override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    val json = savedInstanceState?.getString("CUSTOM_CLASS")
    if (!json!!.isEmpty()) {
        val gson = Gson()
        testBundle = gson.fromJson(json, Session::class.java)
    }
 }
```

You can restore it on Activity `onCreate` also.

**For fragment:**

For put class in `saveInstanceState`:

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = gson.toJson(customClass)
        outState.putString("CUSTOM_CLASS", json)
    }
```

Restore class:

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            val json = savedInstanceState.getString("CUSTOM_CLASS")
            if (!json!!.isEmpty()) {
                val gson = Gson()
                val customClass: CustomClass = gson.fromJson(json, CustomClass::class.java)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should be the best answer, it would be better to provide the dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I know "that this case is cold", but because i found this thread first, when I was searching for exactly the same thing (and found an answer by now):

Imagine Bundle as an XML file.
If you create a new `<BUNDLE name="InstanceName" type="ClassName">`
you can freely add elements and attributes in a fresh and empty namespace.

When `onSaveInstance(Bundle outState)` of your MainActivity is called (you can also force this in `onPause`), you can create a new: `Bundle b = new Bundle();`

Then call your (probably not inherited and not overriden) custom Method `onSaveInstance(Bundle b)` in your own class with your newly created Bundle b.
Then (in `onSaveInstance(Bundle outState)`) of your MainActivity, call `outState.putBundle("StringClassAndInstanceName", b);`

When you find this string in onCreate, you can either use a switch/case to recreate this object or (better) have a factory function in your custom class to work with Bundle and "StringClassAndInstanceName".

Answer (score 2):

Custom objects can be saved inside a Bundle when they implement the interface **Serializable**

Then they can be saved via:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putSerializable("key", myObject)
}
```

Suppose *myObject* is object of class **CustomClass** and **CustomClass** implement the interface **Serializable**

Since the expected *value* in *outState.putSerializable* will be of type **Serializable**, you can pass *myObject* (you can send object of child class where parent class object is expected)

Then they can be used via:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        myObject = savedInstanceState.getSerializable("key") as CustomClass
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31952402)

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) answer.

Basically you have to save it inside a `Bundle`.

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe I wasn't clear enough. What I wanted  to know is how to save a *custom* object. I found that I can make it parcelable.

Answer (score 1):

Custom class objects can be converted to JSON and stored in the bundle as a string. The following example is for Fragments.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json= gson.toJson(customClass);
    outState.putString("CUSTOM_CLASS", json);
}

public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        String json= savedInstanceState.getString("CUSTOM_CLASS");
        if(!json.isEmpty()) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
            CustomClass customClass = gson.fromJson(json, CustomClass.class);
        }
    }
}
```

For Activities, override ***onRestoreInstanceState*** method instead.