# Android save Activity state in Parcelable class object

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

in my application i many `onSaveInstanceState` in each activity and file, now after reading [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172333/how-to-save-an-instance-of-a-custom-class-in-onsaveinstancestate/5130072#5130072) to create `Parcelable` class i can not use that and save into this class

default `onSaveInstanceState` is:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("IsShowingExitDialogs", mIsShowingExitDialogs);
    savedInstanceState.getInt("LastMenuItemSelected", mLastMenuItemSelected);
}
```

now i can not use this below line to save `IsShowingExitDialogs` or `LastMenuItemSelected` to Parcable class:

```
savedInstanceState.putParcelable("IsShowingExitDialogs", mIsShowingExitDialogs);
savedInstanceState.putParcelable("IsShowingExitDialogs", mLastMenuItemSelected);
```

Comment: have you seen my answer ? where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 5):

`Parcelable` is an *interface* applied on classes. It works for *objects*, whereas in your case you are trying to save an **integer** and a **boolean**, both of which are *primitive types*. If you really want to do this, you need to wrap them inside a class that implements `Parcelable`. Then this will work.

**EDIT:**

**1.** The `savedInstanceState` that you *save* in `onSavedInstanceState()` is    returned in `onCreate()` when the `Activity` is recreated, allowing you to reuse the data that you saved previously.

**2.** You need to create a custom class `MyClass extends Parcelable`, implement the interface methods and save it like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(mIsShowingExitDialogs, mLastMenuItemSelected);
savedInstanceState.putParcelable("myClass", myClass);
```

Comment: you dont *save* `savedInstanceState` anywhere, `savedInstanceState` is an object that holds the data you want to save, which is re-accessed in `onCreate()`. You need to create a class `MyClass` that holds the boolean and integer you want to save and implement the `Parcelable` interface on this class. Then save an instance of this class in the `savedInstanceState` object. See edited answer